# Sql Update with join in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Stuck up with an issue in codeigniter. I have the following query:

```
UPDATE
    tbl_print_title 
INNER JOIN tbl_jp_lookups ON tbl_print_title.title_id = tbl_jp_lookups.id
SET
    tbl_print_title.is_delete = 1,
    tbl_jp_lookups.is_delete = 1
WHERE
    tbl_print_title.id = 5
```

I want to write this in codeigniter's query builder structure. It is working fine in phpmyadmin. I tried the following but it does not work. Please provide suggestion.

```
$this->db->set('prt.is_delete', '!is_delete');
$this->db->set('lk.is_delete', '!is_delete'); 
$this->db->where('prt.id',$id);    
$this->db->update(TBL_PRINT_TITLE." as prt");  
$this->db->join(TBL_JP_LOOKUPS." as lk", 'prt.title_id=lk.id'); 
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) { 
return 1;
} else { 
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use below order.
This will first define aliases and then performs the operation

```
$this->db->update(TBL_PRINT_TITLE." as prt");  
$this->db->join(TBL_JP_LOOKUPS." as lk", 'prt.title_id=lk.id'); 
$this->db->set('prt.is_delete', '!is_delete');
$this->db->set('lk.is_delete', '!is_delete'); 
$this->db->where('prt.id',$id);    
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) { 
return 1;
} else { 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: also gives error:

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/smartquote/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1864